# How did the compound 莫 + 非 semantically shift to mean "can it be/is it possible + that"?

Tags: etymology

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary), p 628. I can't access the ["slightly revised through July 2005" ed.](https://wenlin.com/abc%22) [莫非 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8E%AB%E9%9D%9E)
appears correct.

[image]

1. Am I correct that [莫](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8E%AB#Chinese) here means 3 below?

> 1. [none](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/none); [nothing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nothing); [not](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not) [anything](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anything)
> 2. ([literary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#literary) or dialectal [Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_Chinese), dialectal [Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese), [Gan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gan_Chinese), [Hakka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakka_Chinese), [Min Dong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_Dong)) [do](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do) [not](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not); [don't](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don%27t); [must](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/must) not
> 3. particle indicating a [rhetorical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rhetorical#English) [question](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/question#English)
> 4. A [surname](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/surname)​.

2. I don't know which meaning fits [非](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9D%9E#Chinese)?

> 1. [not](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not) [be](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be); [is](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/is) not; [not](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not)
> 2. ([logic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logic)) [NOT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NOT)
> 3. [wrong](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wrong); [incorrect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incorrect)
> 4. to [reproach](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reproach); to [blame](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blame)
> 5. ([colloquial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#colloquial)) Used to insist on something. to [have](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have) [got](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/got) to; to simply [must](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/must)

3. Still I don't understand how these two characters compound to signify "can it be that"?  We're combining merely two characters that signify negation.
4. Don't we need more characters to signify the modal verb 'can', eg "possibility in either a [dynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_modality), [deontic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality), or [epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) sense"? Something feels missing!

Comment: Haha, good question! Maybe 2 negatives make a (possible) positive?? -(-1) = +1??

Comment: @Pedroski 雙重否定句，用兩個否定的詞句表示一個肯定的句子。e.g. 在場的人“無不”贊同此一提案。 他說的“不無”幾分道理。 他的經驗“無非”是讓年輕人得到對未來的啟發。

Answer (score 2):

Both 莫 and 非 denote the sense of ***not***.  The combination 莫非(a double negative) is a set phrase to mean 难道. It's often used to initiate a rhetorical question.

E. g.  莫非你不知道？ / 难道你不知道? // Don't you know it?

Answer (score -2):

watch anime?

莫非 -> "MA SA KA"(まさか)in Japanese...

Hope this will give you both the meaning and context for your understanding.